# Web scraping with Python urllib or requests

Tags: python, web, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to get the latest ratio of gold to USD by scraping information from https://goldprice.org/. How can I do this using `urllib` or `requests` in Python?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urlopen("https://goldprice.org/")
bs=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
lists=bs.findAll(id="gpxtickerLeft_price")
print(lists)
```

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem on your own? What resources did you use? If you've written code, did it return any errors?

Comment: and it return http error 403 forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Utilize Requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = 'https://goldprice.org/'
r = requests.get(url, headers = header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Or if you are using urllib

```
import urllib.request 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = urllib.request.Request('https://goldprice.org/', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
bs = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
```

Comment: I have updated both with Requests and urllib.requests.

Comment: You might be banned. Try changing your proxies and headers.